# CSV in UTF-8 and Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, csv

In my application I have a list of items which can be exported to CSV.

For this, I create a Blob as follows:

```
var BOM = "\ufeff";
var blob = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'csv;charset=utf-8'
});
```

In case that the data in this list contains special characters, the exported file was not opened correctly in MS Excel. So I added a line to my code (the second line in the following snippet), as I found in many Q&A forums:

```
 var BOM = "\ufeff";
 var csv = BOM + csv;
 var blob = new Blob([csv], {
          type: 'csv;charset=utf-8'
 });
```

That works - the CSV is opened correctly in Excel, but then, when saving the file - it is save in text format and not as CSV. Which meant I need to "Save As" the file and change the default type if I want it to be saved correctly.

Is it really like this? Do I really have to choose between the two options - see the file **or** save it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a shame but it is really like this. From `Excel` a `CSV` is `ANSI` encoded per default and there is not a directly possibility to save `CSV` in any unicode encoding. `Microsoft` itself suggest using `Notepad` to change the encoding. See [How to save an address book to a CSV file by using the UTF-8 encoding format so that the CSV file can be imported to Windows Mail](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/933855/how-to-save-an-address-book-to-a-csv-file-by-using-the-utf-8-encoding-format-so-that-the-csv-file-can-be-imported-to-windows-mail). See also [How can I save a csv with utf-8 encoding using Excel 2013?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/how-can-i-save-a-csv-with-utf-8-encoding-using/12801501-c1e4-4a64-80d9-96b680b64cfe)

Only other possibility is using `VBA` and create the `CSV` file using `ADODB.Stream` or `Scripting.FileSystemObject`.

How to use `ADODB.Stream` to create unicode encoded `CSV` file is answered multiple times already. For example: [how to Export excel to csv file with "|" delimted and utf-8 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204239/how-to-export-excel-to-csv-file-with-delimted-and-utf-8-code). Simply change the delimiter "|" to ",". This is the basic approach. Maybe you have to extend it to provide text delimiter also, if the delimiter can be part of the data.

Using [CreateTextFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) of `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is simpler but only allows `Unicode` which is UTF-16LE rather than UTF-8.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more about the other possibility you suggested here?

Comment: OK I now understand. That means I will need to write my code in VBA. in JavaScript I have no other option but to teach my users how to open \ save the exported files?

Comment: Related: [saving text as UTF-8 from Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9093957/11683)

Comment: @user2717436: How to teach Excel to be able opening a UTF-8 encoded CSV properly you have found already: give it a BOM. How to teach the user to be able saving a UTF-8 encoded CSV file from Excel is impossible since Excel can't do this. It will either save CSV ANSI encoded or TXT tabulator delimited and Unicode (UTF-16LE) encoded. So yes for the save part the only possibility is to extend Excel's programming  using VBA or whatever.